# Performing moving average with Na values and min_period=1 pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've following data.

```
    Date        Item_1
    15-03-2021  10
    16-03-2021  20
    17-03-2021  NaN
    18-03-2021  NaN
    19-03-2021  NaN
    20-03-2021  NaN
    21-03-2021  NaN
    22-03-2021  10
    23-03-2021  30
    24-03-2021  NaN
```

I'm trying to calculate moving avergae while ignoring the NaN values. To do that I followed below approach.

```
df.rolling(3,on='Date',min_periods=1).mean()
```

With this I'm getting partially desired result.

```
    Date        Item_1
    15-03-2021  10
    16-03-2021  15
    17-03-2021  15
    18-03-2021  20
    19-03-2021  NaN
    20-03-2021  NaN
    21-03-2021  NaN
    22-03-2021  10
    23-03-2021  20
    24-03-2021  20
```

But as window size is 3 the result I want is :

```
        Date        Item_1
        17-03-2021  15
        18-03-2021  20
        19-03-2021  NaN
        20-03-2021  NaN
        21-03-2021  NaN
        22-03-2021  10
        23-03-2021  20
        24-03-2021  20
```

is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter after `rolling` by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
N = 3
df1 = df.rolling(N,on='Date',min_periods=1).mean().iloc[N-1:]
print (df1)

         Date  Item_1
2  17-03-2021    15.0
3  18-03-2021    20.0
4  19-03-2021     NaN
5  20-03-2021     NaN
6  21-03-2021     NaN
7  22-03-2021    10.0
8  23-03-2021    20.0
9  24-03-2021    20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `window = '3d'` instead:

```
>>> df.rolling('3d', on = 'Date').mean().iloc[2:]
        Date  Item_1
2 2021-03-17    15.0
3 2021-03-18    20.0
4 2021-03-19     NaN
5 2021-03-20     NaN
6 2021-03-21     NaN
7 2021-03-22    10.0
8 2021-03-23    20.0
9 2021-03-24    20.0
```

Comment: This is the same as jezrael's answer and posted 10 minutes after his answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
c = 0
number = 0
a = input()
for i in range(10):
    b = input().split()
    if b[1] != "NaN":
        c = c + int(b[1])
        number += 1
min = c / number
print(min)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works. See [answer].